# Get the Body of a 404 with Grails / Java

Tags: java, http, testing, groovy

Currently I'm testing our REST Implementation. I have the problem, that if a 404 Error is sent (like "User not found") I can get te correct HTP-Header, but not the body / content of the page.

If I call the Page in the Browser I can see the generated JSON Content.

```
    URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection()
    connection.connect()

    if ( connection instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection
        int code = httpConnection.getResponseCode()
        if (code >= 400) {
            assertTrue("Wrong Error Code", code == 404)
        }
    }
```

This is my current code, which works fine. But how do I get the Body of the HTTP Response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the content out of the error stream:

```
def url = 'http://www.google.com/notfound'

URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection()
int code = connection.responseCode
if( code >= 400 ) {
  assert code == 404, "Wrong Error Code (expected 404)"
  println connection.errorStream.text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
String ur=conn.getURL().toString();

Comment: This isn't working because if I open the input stream of the page (with a 404 error) i get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` (had tried this before!)